# How to compile java on unix using -cp

Tags: java, compiler-errors, compilation

i have 3 files i need to compile

the first a.java compiles fine with

```
javac a.java
```

the second requires uses 2 jar files aswell as the file i compiled, a.class. i try to compile the second file with this

```
javac -cp .:firstLib.jar:secondLib.jar b.java
```

i just get errors whenever an instance of the a class appears in the b.java file that says cannot find symbol

i have read that unix uses : and windows uses ; and i have read that i need to point it to the directory that contains the files which is why i need the . as the first in my list i pass to -cp. this attempt finds the two libraries but can not find the a.class that i compiled with the previous line.

the third file i want to compile i can not even try to compile as it is dependent on the second

also worth saying this works fine on my windows pc with eclipse im just moving it to my unix server so there should not be any coding errors

Comment: Is `a` in the root package?

Comment: yes they are all in the root package

Comment: What you have done *should* work ... if you have done it the way that you describe.  I assume that you are compiling `a.java` and `b.java` in the same directory.

Comment: yes all files are in the same directory. and if it matters all i have done to set up java was sudo apt-get install default-jre, which i assumed was fine because helloworld compiles and runs

Answer (score 0):

i found a fix but still do not know why my original attempts did not work

first i moved all java files to a folder called src
second i moved all jar files to a folder called libs
then i compiled a with

```
javac -c ../classes a.java
```

Note: i ran that from the src folder

then i compiled the second with

```
javac -c ../classes -cp ../classes:../libs/* b.java
```

and the third file with

```
javac -c ../classes -cp ../classes:../libs/* c.java
```

i hope this helps someone else that had the same issue i did